# Cancelling SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have been checking similar questions.
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559851/how-to-stop-swingworker-doinbackground-process-immediately) is quite similar what I want to ask but not really I have the answer. Also [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20427697/trying-to-stop-swingworker) I have checked.

Question that I have is that I have a `SwingWorker` which does long processes in the background.

```
    @Override
   protected final List<Object> doInBackground() throws Exception
   {
    //Should I add if(this.isCancelled) here?
    List<Object> objectList = someFecthingMethod();
    //Should I add if(this.isCancelled) here?
    objectList.forEach(object -> executor.submit(new Helper(object));

    this.latch.await();
    //Should I add if(this.isCancelled) here?
    someOtherLongRunningMethodBasedOnHelperResults();
   }
```

In scratch I have a code like that. This runs when calculate button of mine which triggers the worker when it is clicked. I also want to be able to cancel it. I have written needed method `stop()` where it has `cancel()` method of worker itself.

Like below in my Worker Class I have my stop method like below:

```
@Override
public boolean stop()
{
   return this.cancel( true );
}
```

When I call this method, I check in `doInBackground()`, `this.isCancelled()` returns `true.`. But anyway it keeps executing the methods within doInBackground().
So my question is that, should I be adding `if(this.isCancelled())` check before every method in `doInBackground()` to stop it immediately, is there any better way to do stop it from executing when its canceled?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesn't help if that method is already in execution when cancel event occurs.

Comment: @EugenCovaci I am thinking while it is executing `someFetchingMethod()` if cancelling occurs, I would expect it to keep fetching until it returns some result. Then I would expect it to stop running the rest since it is cancelled. This is my question in fact, should I be checking in every step if it is cancelled or not?

Comment: It would be much better if you create a [mcve] instead of giving fragments of the code and then describing changes to those fragments of code. We could run it ourselves and see where you get stuck.

Comment: when you do cancel(true) it will interrupt the code. If we take a look at your worker code it won't be stopped until this.latch.await() that will throw an InteruptedException if the interruption occurred while waiting. If the interruption occurred after you should check often in someOtherLongRunningMethodBasedOnHelperResults() if the tread has been interrupted and stop the process.

Comment: @JEY So I should simply check in every step if the worker is cancelled or not?

Comment: Yes or a more common way is to check for Thread interruption Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted();

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper around that provides the ability to cancel the latch. It will need to track the waiting threads and release them when they timeout as well as remember that the latch was cancelled so future calls to await will interrupt immediately.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understood you.

Comment: @Bleach Something like   /**
     * Unblocks all threads waiting on this latch and cause them to receive an
     * AbortedException.  If the latch has already counted all the way down,
     * this method does nothing.
     */
    public void abort() {
        if( conditionMet)
            return;

        this.aborted = true;
        while(conditionNotMet)
            countDown();
    }